# How to handle check and uncheck checkbox field for store in extjs

Tags: extjs, checkbox, filter, store, extjs4.1

I have a store that loads a grid that displays state name, capital, and Cold Weather.

I also have a checkbox that filters the store depending on the Yes value of 'Cold Weather' column.

When I click the checkbox, the grid filters and shows the states that have 'yes', but when I uncheck the checkbox, it does nothing.

How can I revert back the store to display previous store? Below is my checkboxfield. Please help.

```
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'checkboxfield',
        boxLabel: 'Show only Cold State',
        scope: this,
        handler: function (field, value) {
            scope: this,
            this.checkValue = field.getValue();
            console.log(this.checkValue);
            if (this.checkValue == true) {
                this.store.filter('Cold', 'Yes');
            }
            else if (this.checkValue == false) {
            }
        },
```

**UPDATED CODE** - when I do this, I get this error

> TypeError: tempstore1 is undefined

```
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'checkboxfield',
        boxLabel: 'Show only Cold State',
        scope: this,
        handler: function (field, value) {
            scope: this,
            this.checkValue = field.getValue();
            console.log(this.checkValue);
            if (this.checkValue == true) {
                var tempstore1 = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('store');
                tempstore1.filters.add('CheckBoxFilter', new Ext.util.Filter({
                    property: 'Cold',
                    value: 'Yes',
                    root: 'myTable'
                }));
                console.log('here');
                tempstore1.load();
            }
            else if (this.checkValue == false) {
                this.store.filters.removeAtKey('CheckBoxFilter');
            }
        },
```

**2nd UPDATE** - now I get this error

> TypeError: a.getRoot.call(a, d) is undefined

instead of

```
var tempstore1 = Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('store');
```

I am using

```
var tempstore1 = Ext.getCmp('GridArea1').store;
```

`GridArea1` is the id of my gridpanel.

**3rd UPDATE** - Now I get this error with

```
var tempstore1 = Ext.getCmp('GridArea1').getStore();
```

error from chrome debugger... "true" and "here" are my console.log and so is the "h" part... that is what the tempstore1 has instead of my data..

> true
>   h {hasListeners: e, scope: h, loading: false, events: Object, eventsSuspended: false…}
>   here
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Cold' of undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `clearFilter()`

```
xtype: 'checkboxfield',
boxLabel: 'Show only Cold State',
scope: this,
handler: function (field, value) {
    this.checkValue = field.getValue();
    console.log(this.checkValue);
    if (this.checkValue == true) {
        this.store.filter('Cold', 'Yes');
    }
    else if (this.checkValue == false) {
        this.store.clearFilter();
    }
}
```

It is possible to remove a specific filter (`clearFilter()` removes them all). Instead of using the `store.filter('property_to_filter','value')` method, use:

```
store.filters.add('Coldfilter', new Ext.util.Filter({
    property: 'Cold',
    value: 'Yes',
    root: 'data'
}));
store.load();
```

To remove the filter, use:

```
store.filters.removeAtKey('Coldfilter');
```

There was nothing in the docs about `root: 'data'` to be added in the filter, now it works: http://jsfiddle.net/vrVRP/2/

Comment: Thanks for your answer Pheonix, but this would clear my previous filter. I am not trying to clear the previous filter. The previous filter is triggered by a combobox which I didn't mentiond here. Anyways, your soultion would be easier, but I am trying to go back to the previous filter before I clicked the checkedbox.

Comment: THanks Pheonix... I am trying to implement your answer but getting "expected ','" error... can I do it inside the handler or should I make a function

Comment: THanks Pheonix...actually I am not getting error, but the filter does not work for me.. is it store.load() or do I have to link 'Coldfilter' when applying the filter

Comment: @EagleFox there was nothing in the docs about "root: 'data'" to be added in the filter, now it works: http://jsfiddle.net/vrVRP/2/

Comment: Thanks Pheonix... I know I am getting close... if you please look at the updated code on my post... you can see how I am trying to implement your answer... but I got one error TypeError: tempstore1 is undefined

Comment: @EagleFox: Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('store'); is not returning a store in your code. Try to get the grid store by id using Ext.getCmp("GridId").store and proceed that way.

Comment: Hey Phoenix... now I am getting this error...TypeError: a.getRoot.call(a, d) is undefined... please see my 2nd update... again I can't thank you enough for your time... much appreciated

Comment: @EagleFox use `Ext.getCmp("GridId").getStore()` .... `.store` was working for combo box only, its not for grid.

Comment: @Phoenix... with .getStore() i get this error.. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getStore' of undefined... now do I have to define getStore too

Comment: Hi Phoenix... i got that part sorted but now running at this error... please see my update... thank you

Comment: Hi Phoenix... now I am this close to fixing this... why am I getting that error on my update